# How can I save the canvas as an image instead of downloading it directly?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, save

I have a p5 game and I want to save the canvas as a `p5.Image` so I can show it on the canvas later. However I only found the `saveCanvas()` function which directly downloads an image of the canvas. Is there a way to save it as an image for later use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the p5.js library does not provide a way to do this. However, you can transform it into a data url via this code:

```
const dataURL = document.querySelector("#myCanvas")
                        .toDataURL()
                        .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
```

You can then use this as a regular image source, e.g. you could redirect the current page to the image:

```
window.location.href = dataURL;
```